# Bounty question deleted & will awarding reputation come back

Tags: discussion, badges, bounties

on first bounty you receive a badge `Promoter`

- you have 50 reputation on stake
- the answer that has highest votes is no good but for some reason it is up voted
- according to rules the bounty will be automatically granted

if i delete the question now...

- **Q - 1:** WILL i sill have the Badge `Promoter` ?
- **Q - 2:** is the 50 reputation that was open in market going to come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe bounty questions cannot be deleted. However, if they can, you will keep the badge but the reputation will not be refunded (unless a rep-recalc is done (and even then, I'm not sure)).